# HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: javascript

He visto que tengo este error en mi app, pero no se como eliminarlo exactamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: dice que no encuentra la ruta asignada a ese recurso, por eso es el status 404. Mira si está en esa ruta y sino, prueba forzando el https para esa ruta.

Comment: @gaidyjg disculpa la ignorancia, pero como forzo la ruta?

Comment: Supongo debe ser un asset que tienes en tu carpeta public, así que a lo mejor [esto te sirva](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-secure-asset)

Comment: @BPolando, sino estas usando el SourceMap entonces no es necesario que tu archivo lo tenga, la forma mas facil para que desaparezca esa alerta es irte a la carpeta /js/popper.js.map y al final del documento veras una `Linea "comentada"` elimina esa linea de Source Map y ya deberia de desaparecer esa alert.